# calling wcf from PHP with username authentication

Tags: php, wcf, web-services, web

I'm developing WCF project. Calling WCF services from PHP works fine when the Custom(Username) authentication is off, but when I turn authentication on I can't seem to access WCF services. but I can access WCF services from .NET projects with custom authentication on. its just PHP. I'm using SSL.
below is my binding setting in web.config

```
    <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="MypBinding" allowCookies="true">
              <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
              </security>
            </binding>
     </basicHttpBinding>

<serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="ApiService.UAuth, ApiService"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
```

and below is my sample php code:

```
 <?php 
 header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    echo "start -> ";

    echo " set wsdl var11111 -> ";


    $soapclient = new SoapClient('https://api.address.com/Apii.svc?wsdl', array('login' => "username",'password' => "pwd",'default_socket_timeout' => 120, 'trace' => true));

    echo " created soapclient ->";
    echo $soapclient->GetData()->GetDataResult;
    echo " end ";


    print ' caught exception:'. $e->getMessage(). "\n";
    return;
?>
```

any suggestion will be much appreciated!

Comment: Hi Sprinter Did you get this done, I am facing the same issue.Can you provide some help here??